# Proof that number 7 is eigenvalue of matrix product.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A,B \in M_{7 \times 7} (\mathbb{R})$ and let $7$ is eigenvalue of matrix $AB$ for eigenvector $v$. Prove that $7$ is eigenvalue of matrix $BA$.

So i know that $(AB)v = 7v$ and I have to prove that exist $w$ such that $(BA)w = 7w$. I have not any idea how can I do it. I will grateful for your help and hint.

Answer (score 4):

Since $(AB)v=7v$ so multilying by $B$ on the left gives:
$$B(AB)v=(BA)Bv=7Bv$$
so $Bv$ is an eigenvector of $BA$  associated to the eigenvalue $7$.

**Added** $\ $ Notice that $v$ isn't in the nullspace of $B$ otherwise $Bv=0$ and then $(AB)v=A0=0=7v$ so we find $v=0$ which's a contradiction.

Comment: This assumes that $v$ is not in the nullspace of $B$. That is, $Bv \neq 0$. Is this implied in $B\in M_{7 \times 7}(R)$?

Comment: $v$ isn't in the nullspace of $B$ otherwise $Bv=0$ and then $(AB)v=A0=0=7v$ so we find $v=0$ which's a contradiction.

Comment: Ah, yes, good point.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane That is an important part of the solution, so you should probably add it to your answer.

Comment: @VedranŠego Done! Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$u:=Bv\implies Au=ABv=7v\implies BAu=BA(Bv)=B(ABv)=B(7v)=7\cdot Bv=7u\ldots$$